# ExtJs Toolbar not automatic wrapped as per width

Tags: javascript, extjs

my problem is not wrapped tool bar automatically as per width in extjs frame worked.

Example:

Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', {
    renderTo: document.body,
    width: 200,
    items: [{

```
        text: 'Button'
    }, {
        xtype: 'splitbutton',
        text: 'Split Button'
    },

    '->', {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'field1',
        emptyText: 'enter search term'
    },

    '-',
    'text 1', {
        xtype: 'tbspacer'
    },
    'text 2', {
        xtype: 'tbspacer',
        width: '50%'
    },
    'text 3'
]
```

});

Comment: my expected result is not my toobar cut but it's wrap as per with. any confusion and send me message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `enableOverflow` config for that. Below is an example of it.

```
xtype: 'toolbar',
dock: 'top',
enableOverflow: true
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe are you looking for `overflowHandler` and `scrollable` parameters.

Example on fiddle:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2qt1

Comment: scrolling show every time. my requirement is when not proper space then enable scrolling